# Discord.js Guild Specific Command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How would I make a specific command only work in a specific server. What I'm attempting to do:

The server: 
Hello! Thanks for ... . . !

A different server:
Blank, unresponsive.

Can someone help ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you already know? Just asking the community to do all your work is no welcome on Stackoverflow

Comment: Well, I have a command that displays information of a specific server.

This is the command.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/towefaqeki.js ------ I attempted to use     let guildId = message.guild.id;
   let guild = bot.guilds.get(688757748229472263); , but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can edit your answer to include the code directly in it, that's way better than a hastebin link

Comment: I know but it's to large for it. 

Answer (score 1):

You can check `guild.id`. 
Try reading what parameters the [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object has. I think this will help you solve fairly simple questions :)

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    if ( message.guild.id === 'SOME GUILD ID') {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    }
});
```